# Why limit 2 result is not a superset of limit 1 result?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a temp table in snowflake and query it with the following command

```
select mykey
from   myDB
limit  1;
```

The query returns result 'X'

Then I use the following command

```
select mykey
from   myDB
limit  2;
```

The query returns result 'Y' and 'Z'. Question:

Why the result returned from the second query is not a superset of the result from first query?

Comment: you don't have an ordered by clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no ORDER BY clause, thus your data is not forced into a stable sorted order, thus the limit may not be looking at the same rows.

Comment: Moreover, without an explicit order, if you run the very same query twice in a row, you're not guarranted to get the same rows.

Comment: @Alejandro, yes, the reason for this is what I am looking for? I understand that this can be a complex topic. Can you guys suggest some reading for me to do?

Comment: @drdot "it complex" and it's also "simple". If you have data in 10K files, and you asked for "1 row of data" a system can return you a "row" from the file it last read and thus has in memory. Another reason might be based on last written data. Another reason might be related to the system might make 2+ parallel reads for files (code word for data partitions) and which ever is returned first from the data layer is the one returned. Now there is also cache's that interact with this class of thing.

Comment: But the simple part is if you just need any rows, ask for it, but if you want the newest row with respect to a date field, order by that date field.